# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContract')

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

Receiving the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'getContract)
When I run : $'yarn hardhat test' (to test sol. contract FundMe{})
The problem is directed at  line 20:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContract')
at Context. (test\unit\FundMe.test.js:20:31)

```
const {deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
// const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const {assert } = require("chai")

describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    beforeEach(async function() {
       const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts()
        await deployments.fixture(['all']) 
       *** fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer) ***
          
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract("MockV3Aggregator", deployer
      )
    }) 
   describe("constructor", async function() {
      it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function (){
        const response = await fundMe.priceFeed()
        assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address)
    })
      })
    })
```

I have tried replacing getContract() with getContractAt() and getContractFactory()  with same results.  Also looked in files for misspelling and variable structures

- deploy-fund-me
- FundMe.test.js
  -hardhat.config.js
  &  FundMe.sol

VS code is giving me a 3 dot line under getContract() ==> Property 'getContract' may not exist on type 'typeof import 
When I click on INdex in the pop up box it gives this info.  a list of import and export strings comeup, getContract() is not in that list.

Am I missing some dependencies or add-ons ?
"devDependencies": {
"@ethersproject/abi": "^5.7.0",
"@ethersproject/providers": "^5.7.2",
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.6",
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.8",
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.1",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.2",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.6",
"@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.2.0",
"@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.5",
"chai": "^4.3.7",
"ethers": "5.7.2",
"hardhat": "^2.12.7",
"hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.23",

Comment: is the name of the contract "FundMe"

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the package @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers in your project
2. Add `import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle"` on your hardhat.config.ts
   (or .js)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and run this command:

With **npm**:

```
npm i -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers
```

With **yarn**:

```
yarn add --dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between getContract & getContractFactory & getContractAt

**ethers.getContract() :**

> Returns a new connection to a contract at contractAddressOrName with the contractInterface. and it's used to connect to a contract

**ethers.getContractFactory() :**

> Returns a JavaScript object that represents a smart contract factory. and it's used to deploy new instances of the smart contract.

**ethers.getContractAt() :**

> Returns an instance of a smart contract that has already been deployed to the Ethereum network. It takes the Ethereum address of an existing smart contract as an argument and returns an object that represents this specific instance of the contract.